# Is there a way to get Spring MVC to do a "pretty print" formatting on the HTML result before replying to the browser?

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, tiles

I have a web app build with Java, Spring MVC, Tiles, JSP, Bootstrap, jQuery.

The HTML pages they get sent during the browser are mostly dynamically generated and assembled from a variety of HTML fragments.

The web application works fine, but when you view the code in the browser, the formatting can be quite erratic because different pieces of HTML are using different indenting and line spacing.

QUESTION: Is there a way with Spring MVC (or something else) to "pretty print" the resulting HTML page so the formatting is always nice and clean every time?

Comment: There is probably a browser plugin that can help you. Why would you optimize the page for human readability? Let the browser handle that ifyou want to "debug" HTML.

Comment: It's all about appearances for a client. The client who will run the app is particular about code formatting ... they're used to building web apps in house and they take well-formatted code as an indication that it is well-designed.  So I'd like all the web page code produced by my web app to be as nicely formatted as possible.

Comment: I would look for a different client... If they are considering such low-level details over functionality and usability...

Comment: It's superficial but appearances are important.  I googled and found similar solutions for pretty-printing JSON results.  Seems like there should be a solution for pretty-printing HTML too.  Perhaps I'll build one. :). Thanks for the chat.  (Also, I'll work for any client who pays me, no judging.)